# (Joomla 1.6) Template position descriptions don't refresh

Tags: joomla, template, language

I want to change a description of a template position, so when I go to Admin->Extensions->Module Manager I see a different description of a module position in the position list when I edit a module.

However, when I change (for instance) the template 'beez_20' and want to rename the name of the position 'debug', I change the description (TPL_BEEZ_20_POSITION_DEBUG) in the language file 'languages\en-GB\en-GB.tpl_beez_20.sys.ini' to something different, say 'Abracadabra'.

However, the changes don't appear in the position list and I can find no reference whatsoever of how or when the ini files are read or maybe cached.

Does anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself... actually quite stupid.
The language files of a template are moved to the folder 'language' in the Joomla root. And these are the ones I should edit, not the ones in the template's folder.